# Wso2 API Manager error - Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream, errorcode - 601000

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using API Manager to define to connection using oath 2.0. I  have done all the configurations and connection is working. But some of the requests comes with the following error

```
{
    "code": "601000",
    "type": "Status report",
    "message": "Runtime Error",
    "description": "Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream"
}
```

and look likes the the response has content type application/fhir+json. I have seen some articles to add the content-type in the axis.xml file. Can someone please advise how I can add this content type in the wso2 api manager so that it recognize this content type.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following configurations to the **repository/conf/deployment.toml**.

```
[[custom_message_builders]]
content_type = "application/fhir+json"
class = "org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"

[[custom_message_formatters]]
content_type = "application/fhir+json"
class = "org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"
```

Comment: The connection is defined in API manager only. How I can access this file for api manager? Or is this is for micro integrator?

Comment: The file `repository/conf/deployment.toml` is available in the API manager.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is fixed now

Comment: ,Can you please advise on this question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73243035/wso2-email-connector-issue-with-sending-attachments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73243035/wso2-email-connector-issue-with-sending-attachments 
Can u please answer this question too @Arunan Sugunakumar