# WSO2 email connector - Issue with sending attachments

Tags: email, email-attachments, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm working on an email connector that is sending emails successfully.

But I want to send emails with an attachment.

I am using email connector 1.0.2 that support the attachments in its payload.

```html
<email.send configKey="EMAIL_CONNECTION_SMTP">
    <from>{json-eval($.from)}</from>
    <to>{json-eval($.to)}</to>
    <subject>{json-eval($.subject)}</subject>
    <content>{$ctx:DecodedBodyTemplate}</content>
    <contentType>{$ctx:contentType}</contentType>
    <attachments>{json-eval($.attachments)}</attachments> 
</email.send>
```

And the payload has:

```js
"attachments": [
    {
        "name": "sampleimagefile.txt",
        "content": "This is a text file"
    }
]
```

I tried using `base64encoded` string in content too.

Yet I'm still receiving emails without any attachment.

Comment: @arunan-sugunakumar

Answer (score 0):

I also use email connector 1.0.2 and I don't have any issue sending attachments.

Look [here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/connectors/email-connector/email-connector-config/) for more info.

So, your payload should look like this:

```
{
    "from": "user1@gmail.com",
    "to": "user2@gmail.com",
    "subject": "This is the subject",
    "content": "This is the body",
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "name": "sampleimagefile.png",
            "content": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
        }
    ]
}
```